# User specific content (posts) / limiting visibility

Tags: plugins, customization

I need some help. My wife teaches french, and I would like to set up website for her. The problem is I don't know so much about wordpress and googling did not help as well.

I know how to make simple wordpress site, but how do I make something like intranet. I mean that every one of her students would have there own simple page, so she can put their homework and so on.

Can someone please point me to the right direction. Some tutorials or plugins, so I could dig into it.

---

### Update:

I will try to explain more, because I think I'm doing it wrong way. So basically now, when some student logs in, he can see a new link (homework - for example), and when he clicks on it, he sees what he needs to do and read.

But this info must be specific to him, cuz she teaches students individually.

So I want to have one page, where loop displays posts that are intended only for logged in user.

Yesterday I tried "user specific content", it works ok, but it shows headlines of all posts. Only the text is hidden. (I mean I can still see all posts, but I can just read the ones that are assigned to me).

So guys, any advice? Should I sort posts with loop? (can some plug in help me, because I'm just a novice in php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is hard to give you a full solution, mine is just a direction.

Install the free good and well known plugin [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/).

Using that plugin:

> you can create many-to-many relationships between posts and users

So after you create a relation between students (as users) and posts (probably CPT) you need also

- Create an archive page that shows only post connected to current user (look for `pre_get_posts` action)
- Create single view that checks if current user is the one related to post and if not redirect or show something else (look for `template_redirect` action or `template_include` action)
- Last thing you have to avoid logged user with specific role (students) can view backend, after login (and every time they try to view dashboard) they should be redirected to your customized archive (first item in this list). A search here in wpse will help you for this.

Try to implement step by step, and if you have problems ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

In a Wordpress site you can add users as contributors. The students write a post and the post rests as 'pending'. She will can add users manually or enable the contributors registration. You can structure the content using categories: one for the teacher, another for the students, etc.

The second option is to install the plugin bbPress. It will creates a little forum. The students can attach their homework into the forum.

There's a third option which is out of the context: Wordpress + Moodle.

Answer (score 0):

I came across Wootheme's Sensei and browsed it a bit. I believe it PERFECT for what you're trying to do but haven't had a chance to use it myself yet.

http://www.woothemes.com/products/sensei/

Comment: Thanks for advice **BenRacicot** , but I don't want to spend $150 at the moment, because I just need a simple simple page.